# Gitlab revoke canceling pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

is there any way to revoke possibility to canceling jobs in pipelines in Gitlab 9? I couldnt find such an option in admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet possible as of Gitlab 9.4